# can I pass parameter from a function in onprepare to overwrite protractor config file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to call a function(promise) in the onprepare state that would return a specs array of all the tests that needs to be run; I need to pass that to the specs in config file

```
var Excel_Input = require('./Utility/Excel_Input.js');
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');
var specArray=[''];
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs:specArray,
  allScriptsTimeout: 400000,
  getPageTimeout: 400000,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000,
  },

      params: {
      },

  onPrepare: async function() {
      var excelData = new Excel_Input();
     await excelData.readFromExcel('dir','sheetName').then(function (result) { 
             specArray.push(result[0].specPath);
             console.log("spec Array: "+specArray); 
        });
       browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
           baseDirectory: './../XO_Protractor_SOM/Reports/screenshots'
        }).getJasmine2Reporter());
     }
};
```

the console prints:

```
spec Array: ,Progression/sampleTest.js
```

but it is not overwriting the actual specs in config file

Answer (score 0):

Moving read excel code block from `onPrepare()` to head of file.

```
var Excel_Input = require('./Utility/Excel_Input.js');
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');

var excelData = new Excel_Input();
var execSpecs= await excelData.readFromExcel('dir','sheetName');

var specArray=[''];
specArray.push(execSpecs[0].specPath);
console.log("spec Array: "+specArray); 

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs:specArray,
  allScriptsTimeout: 400000,
  getPageTimeout: 400000,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000,
  },

  params: {
  },

  onPrepare: function() {    
    browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
       baseDirectory: './../XO_Protractor_SOM/Reports/screenshots'
    }).getJasmine2Reporter());
  }
};
```